# How to get apk from react native codes

Tags: android, ios, react-native

How to get apk from react native code
I am using react native expo for my code compilation, i have done all my codes and i need to know how my code to be converted to use in ios and android devices

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation at all? https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/ Basically any answer here is going to mirror the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the following steps which are need to generate apk and IPA using expo

**1. Install Expo CLI**

Expo CLI is the tool for developing and building Expo apps

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

If you haven't created an Expo account before, you'll be asked to create one when running the build command.

**2. Configure app.json**

App.json contained information about apk and IPA both. These are the information which is mention in app.json

Application name
Application version 
SDK version 
Application icon 
Android package name 
IOS bundleindentifier

Some other information also mention in it

```
{ 
"expo": { 
"name": "Your App Name", 
"icon": "./path/to/your/app-icon.png",
"version": "1.0.0", 
"slug": "your-app-slug", 
"sdkVersion": "XX.0.0", 
"ios": { "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.yourappname" }, 
"android": { "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname"
   }
  }
 }
```

**3. Start the build**

For apk run this command

```
expo build:android
```

For IPA generation run this command

```
expo build:ios
```

**4. Check build status**

Run following command to check apk and IPA

```
expo build:status
```

For more information related to apk and ipa generation please check following [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/)